# Broadcast Receiver: Why it doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this Broadcast Receiver that gets and keeps up to date information on the battery. For information about the battery works well, in the sense that they are updated without having to recreate the Activity, while the WiFi no. For example, if I disable the WiFi does not change the Summary of Preference (and should). Why? How can I fix? This is the code.

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    unregisterReceiver(batteryInfoReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart()
{
    this.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    super.onRestart();
}

private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();

    int level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
    String technology= intent.getExtras().getString(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY);
    int temperature= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0)/10;
    int voltage= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE,0);

    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
    if (sdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        boolean wCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS;

        if(wCharge) {
            ricarica.setSummary("Charging (WiFi)");
        }
    }

    if(usbCharge) {
        ricarica.setSummary("Charging (USB)");
    }
    else if (acCharge){
        ricarica.setSummary("Charging (AC)");
    }

    else {
        ricarica.setSummary("Not charging");
    }

    livelloBatteria.setSummary("Battery at "+level+"%");
    livelloVoltaggio.setSummary(voltage+" mV");
    livelloTemperatura.setSummary(Integer.toString(temperature)+"° Celsius");
    tecnologia.setSummary(technology);

    int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    int speed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
    String speedString = Integer.toString(speed);
    String mac = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
    String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);

    if (wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled()){

    if(mac!=null) {
        indirizzoMac.setSummary(mac);
    }
    else {
        indirizzoMac.setSummary("Unkown");
    }

    if(ipAddress!=null) {
    indirizzoIp.setSummary(ipAddress);
    }
    else {
        indirizzoIp.setSummary("Unkown");
    }

    if(ssid!=null) {
        indirizzoSsid.setSummary(ssid);
    }
    else {
        indirizzoSsid.setSummary("Unkown");
    }

    if(speedString!=null) {
        velocità.setSummary(speedString+" Mbps");
    }

    else {
        velocità.setSummary("Unkown");
    }

    }

    else {
        indirizzoIp.setSummary("WiFi disabled");
        indirizzoSsid.setSummary("WiFi disabled");
        velocità.setSummary("WIFi disabled");
        indirizzoMac.setSummary(mac);
    }
    }
    };
```

Comment: Can you post the manifest? have you correctly set intent filter to capture connectivity events?

Comment: You have registered your BroadcastReceiver with correct intent-filter in Manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your receiver is not registered for wifi connectivity change try adding another filter to it:

```
IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
filter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
this.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver,filter);
```

You can also add connectivity change action to filter so that your onReceive will get called if network connectivity changes:

```
filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
```

Comment: It works but now i've a problem. When i disable and after enable the WiFi in my Preference read <unkown ssid>, IP Address 0.0.0.0 and speeds -1 Mbps. Why and how can i solve this issue?